# How are parameters passed in function calls in CIL?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil

I am trying to learn CIL code, but not able to undertsand how return value of one function is passed as a parameter to another function.

I have generated CIL code for the below function:

```
  public bool TestWebPage()
  {
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.costco.com");
    request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
  }
```

CIL code:

```
//000021:     public void TestWebPage()
//000022:     {
    IL_0000:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
   .line 23,23 : 7,71 ''
//000023:       WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.costco.com");
IL_0001:  /* 72   | (70)000001       */ ldstr      "http://www.costco.com" /* 70000001  */
  IL_0006:  /* 28   | (0A)000012       */ call       class [System/*23000003*/]System.Net.WebRequest/*01000016*/ [System/*23000003*/]System.Net.WebRequest/*01000016*/::Create(string) /* 0A000012 */
  IL_000b:  /* 0A   |                  */ stloc.0
.line 24,24 : 7,70 ''
//000024:       request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
IL_000c:  /* 06   |                  */ ldloc.0
IL_000d:  /* 6F   | (0A)000013       */ callvirt   instance class [System/*23000003*/]System.Net.IWebProxy/*01000017*/ [System/*23000003*/]System.Net.WebRequest/*01000016*/::get_Proxy() /* 0A000013 */
IL_0012:  /* 28   | (0A)000014       */ call       class [System/*23000003*/]System.Net.ICredentials/*01000019*/ [System/*23000003*/]System.Net.CredentialCache/*01000018*/::get_DefaultCredentials() /* 0A000014 */
IL_0017:  /* 6F   | (0A)000015       */ callvirt   instance void [System/*23000003*/]System.Net.IWebProxy/*01000017*/::set_Credentials(class [System/*23000003*/]System.Net.ICredentials/*01000019*/) /* 0A000015 */
IL_001c:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
.line 25,25 : 7,73 ''
```

Specifically, I am not able to understand the following things in CIL code:

1. How does the CLR runtime know that set_Credentials is to be passed the value returned from get_DefaultCredentials, since there does not seem to be any link other than the commented part "/*01000019*/"?
2. How does CLR call get_Proxy on current instance of System.Net.WebRequest, i.e, is there a pointer to instance number in the CIL code?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, they are passed on the stack - but note that this is largely an implementation detail ;p

1: the stack is built up such that the *target* is on the stack first = specifically:

- ldloc.0 loads request onto the stack
- callvirt get_Proxy() consumes request (since virtual) and leaves the proxy on the stack (from the return value)
- call get_DefaultCredentials() doesn't consume anything, and appends the default credentials
- callvirt set_Credentials consumes 2 values; the first (the proxy) is used as the instance (since virtual); the second (the credentials) is used as the first parameter value

2: In this case the instance is held in a "local" to the method (i.e. a reserved slot relative to the stack-frame); in this case, loc 0. In a release build, I would actually expect loc 0 to be removed, and this all handled simply without reserved slots; "dup" (to copy the reference as needed) would most-likely be used rather than stloc/ldloc.

Answer (score 1):

1. The [call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx) instruction on `IL_0012` pushes the return value of the `get_DefaultCredentials` onto the stack and the `set_Credentials` method on the next line is passed as argument the value onto the evaluation stack.
2. The `request` variable returned by the `WebRequest.Create` method is stored as a local variable at index 0 ([stloc.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc.aspx)) and is then loaded by [ldloc.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloc.aspx) so the `get_Proxy` method on line `IL_000d` is called on this local variable variable which has been loaded onto the evaluation stack.

Answer (score 0):

It's all stack based. What happens is that the result of calling a method which returns a value `get_DefaultCredentials` is pushed on to the evaluation stack.

There's no magic link, the value just happens to reside on top of the stack.

Just look at the constructor call, the first thing that happens is that the string `"http://www.costco.com"` is pushed on top the evaluation stack. Then the constructor is called. The constructor then pops values of the evaluation stack. The last value pushed on top the stack is the last parameter. `ldstr` pushes exactly one value on top the stack. The result of the constructor call which is now the *top* and that reference is then popped and stored in location 0 `stloc.0` (a local variable).

Calling instance methods is slightly different, the first argument in that case is always the object so the first call you see here is `ldloc.0`. Which pushes the `WebRequest` object instance on top the evaluation stack. From here we call the `get_Proxy` methods it consumes the value on top the evaluation stack put there by `ldloc.0` and returns the object instance returned. This is effectively replacing the value on top of the evaluation stack. Now however, the top of the stack is not longer the value that `ldloc.0` put there.

Nothing is really being passed, it's just pushed and popped, off and on the stack.